# How to hide navigation bar permenantly on screen touch

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to hide the navigation bar when some conditions are true so I have tried to hide the navigation bar when user touhc the screen. Here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (condition) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

The problem when I touch the screen, navigation bar appears on screen and second touch makes it dissappear. This situation is repeated in every two touch.
How can I make the navigation bar permenantly dissaper while my condtion true?

Comment: Try adding a boolean with true value, check this boolean in your if condition and make it false inside your if condition. If nav bar appears again without code inside your condition got executed, you should look for the cause somwhere else in your code.

Comment: As a measure of security (ie keeping people from building apps that essentially BRICK phones) you can NOT permanently hide the system navigation

Comment: I am not permenantly hide it. I am trying to hide it under control of admin. When admin enters his password and the pass is correct I want to hide it on screen touch. I have checked it. When my condition is true code is running but navigation bar appears on screen after touching the screen. If hiding navigation bar is not possible I will try to disable functionality of navigation buttons.